# How can we perform matrix factorisation for three dimensional matrix?

Tags: python, categorical-data, matrix, recommender-system, tensor

I am working on the recommendation system in which I have three factors `user_id`, `time` and `product_id`.SO how can we do the factorisation for three variables and predict the values for the other users from these three dimensional matrices.

---

So can we use SVD three dimensional matrix factorisation for recommendation system?

Answer (score 1):

Low-rank decomposition is less straightforward for three-way arrays than two-way matrices, and less unique.  One popular decomposition in chemometrics is PARAFAC, which writes an array $X$ as
$$X_{ijk} =\sum_{f=1}^F a_ib_jc_k +e_{ijk}$$
and tries to minimise $e$, analogous to SVD in two dimensions.

Here's a tutorial/review on [PARAFAC](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ebhiksha/courses/mlsp.fall2013/lectures/Parafac.pdf)

[Tucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tucker_decomposition) decompositions are a bit more general than PARAFAC, allowing structure that isn't just a product of three one-dimensional vectors.